# Graph correlation discovery algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, correlation

I'm not a mathematician, so I'll try to describe this in a layperson's terms.

I'm trying to take two time series, which could represent any variable quantity, maximum daily temperature, stock price high of the day, etc.  These would be multiplied by a factor that would make their maxima and minima correspond.  (E.g., two temperature series might range between different coldest and warmest temperatures, but in both I'd treat coldest as 0% and warmest as 100%.)

Given this, I want to find out what relative shift in their start times would produce the "most" correlation.  That is, the longest sample period with a "high" correlation.  (I know that's a bit fuzzy.)

As a simple example, given last year's temperatures for several cities, it might choose two cities that both had a period of several weeks in which every other day had a maximum temperature that was 2/3 of the preceding day.  This didn't necessarily start for both cities on the same day.  That's where the time shifting trials come in.

A pointer to a discussion, pseudo code, or actual utility library would be good.

Comment: You could also try asking @ [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @J. M.: Thanks.  Didn't know about it.  I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to calculate [Cross-Correlations.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation)

Comment: That's it, precisely!  Wow. I independently invented them, and didn't even know it.  ;)

Comment: @Buggieboy Ha! now you may try to independently invent the methods for calculating them efficiently! :)

Comment: I'm afraid I might have less luck there!

Comment: @Buggieboy My 2 cents ... http://scribblethink.org/Work/nvisionInterface/nip.html and http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~deaton/remarks_ncc.html Good Luck!